# Is there a way to instruct the GPU not to resolve drawing conflicts that result from overlap?

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, gpu

In IOS, is there a way to instruct the GPU not to resolve drawing conflicts that result from overlap from drawing a large number of line segments that often cross each other (maybe something in Open GL)?  The line segments are all the same color and the alpha is 1.0 so there is no need for the GPU to worry about what might appear on top when overlapped pixels exist.   I suspect that if I can get the GPU to not waste effort in resolving the overlapping drawing conflicts that my algorithm will be able to operate at full speed at all times since I always draw the same number of lines.

I ask because I have developed a smooth curve morphing algorithm that uses a library of complex but artful geometric shapes.  The algorithm continuously morphs to some next shape from the library.  I run this on an iPad, and with the high resolution screen, it’s a very unique and artistic effect.   I notice that the drawing of the morphing curve slows down when there are many crossing lines in the drawing.  This will occur at 2 times.  If 1 of the shapes has a lot of twists and turns and as a result a lot of crossing lines, then the drawing process noticeably becomes chunky and slower than normal.  The other occurrence is if 1 of the shapes being morphed to is a single point.  In that instance, even simpler shapes without a lot of twists and turns has the appearance of shrinking it’s scale down towards the single point.  As it gets close to the singularity, the shape is so small that the line width and scale now cause a lot of overlapping of the drawn lines, and slowed drawing occurs.

I have included a code snippet below, that shows the drawing calls that I am making, but I blanked out things that are proprietary to my algorithm with the word PROPRIETARY.
Please note that I draw well over 1000 lines per frame, so there is quite a bit of detail that can be shown.  In general, the more detail shown, the more artistic and aesthetic the drawing.  My base equations have 100 quintillion possible combinations, that’s one and 20 zeros (100,000,000,000,000,000,000) so as you can imagine, the resulting smooth curves have many interesting shapes and loops possible with some being symmetric and some being asymmetric and yet having artistic merit.  Indeed, one of the curves I have found looks much like a wolves face outline, with ears chin, cheeks, etc.

The smooth curve morphing base code was approved by Apple yesterday in the iCanMorph app as one of 65 artful drawing modes.  This effect is only currently included in the iPad version.  If you decide to examine the slowed drawing effect that I am experiencing (the app is free), it best to use a newer iPad with a faster processor.  On an iPad Air, the algorithm keeps up very nicely, except once in a while under the conditions described above. Once inside iCanMorph, press the Modes button at the bottom left side, then select the Smooth Curve Morphing mode.

See :
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icanmorph/id718045966?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4
http://www.logicenginedesigns.com

If the smooth curve morphing concept interests you in ways, please note that in the next release (submitted last night to Apple) and due out in a week, that I have enabled users to search the random possibilities, and when they find unique and artful shapes, they can feedback to me the equation coefficients and I will include their found artful curves in the next weekly release, along with the name of their school (college, high school, grade school, and even preschool!).  I expect the app to quickly have several thousand shapes in it’s database.  There are also plans to let users specify a “string” of shape identifiers where they can choose any subset of the shapes to continuously repeat morphing.

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[] = {rComponent, gComponent, bComponent, 1.0};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    PROPRIETARY = PROPRIETARY(PROPRIETARY);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, PROPRIETARY, PROPRIETARY);


    [self setBackgroundColor:latestBackgroundColor];

    int i = 1;

    for (i=1; i < PROPRIETARY + 1; i++)
    {
        if (PROPRIETARY == 1) {
            PROPRIETARY = 0;
            CGContextStrokePath(context);

            PROPRIETARY = (float)i * 2/PROPRIETARY;
            PROPRIETARY = PROPRIETARY(PROPRIETARY);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, PROPRIETARY, PROPRIETARY);

        } else
        {
            PROPRIETARY = (float)i * 2/PROPRIETARY;
            PROPRIETARY = PROPRIETARY(PROPRIETARY);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pathPointOnCurveAB.x, pathPointOnCurveAB.y);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pathPointOnCurveAB.x, pathPointOnCurveAB.y);
        }

    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);
```

Comment: For posterity and for anyone who reviews my question, setting the below properties made the drawing much smoother on the complex shapes.
 
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.layer.opaque = YES;
 
    self.layer.drawsAsynchronously = YES;
I think it was the .opaque property that showed the most improvement in performance.  I read up on OpenGl some, and I might try to draw my lines that way soon, as it might even show better performance for the unique shape morphing that I am doing in iCanMorph.